# wrong numbering in subfigure environment when caption is on top

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subfloats

I got wrong numbering with `\subfigure` environment when I use `\ref` to call a figure in the text. The problem only happens when I change caption position to the top of the figures (and yes, I need on top). Here an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\caption[Optional caption for list of figures]{Caption of subfigures \subref{fig:subfig1}, \subref{fig:subfig2} and \subref{fig:subfig3}}
\subfigure[Caption of subfigure 1]{
\rule{4cm}{3cm}
\label{fig:subfig1}
}
\subfigure[Caption of subfigure 2]{
\rule{4cm}{3cm}
\label{fig:subfig2}
}
\subfigure[Caption of subfigure 3]{
\rule{4cm}{3cm}
\label{fig:subfig3}
}
\label{fig:subfigureExample}
\end{figure}
Reference to figure \ref{fig:subfigureExample}. Second figure is \ref{fig:subfig2}.
\end{document}
```

PS: I know `subfigure` is obsolete but it's used many times in this document. I want to try to fix this bug instead of substitute everything by `subfloat`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) provides the option `figtopcap` which assumes that you'll use a `fig`ure `cap`tion at the `top` of the figure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[figtopcap]{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption[Optional caption for list of figures]{Caption of subfigures 
    \subref{fig:subfig1}, \subref{fig:subfig2} and \subref{fig:subfig3}}

  \subfigure[Caption of subfigure 1]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig1}
  }
  \subfigure[Caption of subfigure 2]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig2}
  }
  \subfigure[Caption of subfigure 3]{
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}
    \label{fig:subfig3}
  }
  \label{fig:subfigureExample}
\end{figure}
Reference to figure \ref{fig:subfigureExample}. Second figure is \ref{fig:subfig2}.
\end{document}
```

If you only do this occasionally (and don't want a global option set during package load), you have to add `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` after the `\caption`.

---

Here is an option using [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=bottom,labelformat=simple,font=small}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption[Optional caption for list of figures]{Caption of subfigures \subref{fig:subfig1}, \subref{fig:subfig2} and \subref{fig:subfig3}}

  \subcaptionbox{Caption of subfigure 1\label{fig:subfig1}}{%
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}%
  }
  \subcaptionbox{Caption of subfigure 2\label{fig:subfig2}}{%
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}%
  }
  \subcaptionbox{Caption of subfigure 3\label{fig:subfig3}}{%
    \rule{4cm}{3cm}%
  }
  \label{fig:subfigureExample}
\end{figure}
Reference to figure \ref{fig:subfigureExample}. Second figure is \ref{fig:subfig2}.
\end{document}
```